# while having elements slide, make wrapper div width decrease

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a simple div wrapper called `.falling` within this div I have 10 small images. I created a simple function that allows them to 'slide down' when I desire. That code is below.

**JS**:

```
function slide(){
    $(".falling").delay(100).fadeIn().animate({opacity: 1, top:"300px"},'slow');}
slide();
```

**CSS**:

```
.falling { 
  width: 500px;
  left: 600px;
  top: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  display:none;
}
```

The problem is; 2 things. One, at the end of the '`slide down`' I would like to have the `.falling` wrapper `width` to DECREASE so down to maybe `250px;` because I want the illusion the images are grouping together at the end. Each img has a shared class called `.imgfall` I would like to use this to make the images smaller in width at the bottom as well. So, maybe `max-width: 25px;`

```
function slide(){
  $(".falling").delay(100).fadeIn().animate({opacity: 1, top:"300px"},'slow');
  $(".falling").css("width", "250px"); // tried this before and after slide but doesn't resize after slide but instead before, so not working!
}
slide();
```

Comment: This has both `jquery` and `css3` as categories, does that mean you are looking for either type of answer? It looks like this could be done `css3` if you want it to as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling a function as the last parameter in jquery's animate function, you basically call an 'on complete'. See: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
    var $fallingShell = $(".falling");
    var animateSlides = function(){
      function slide(){
        $fallingShell.delay(100).fadeIn().animate({opacity: 1, top:"300px"},'slow', function(){
          $fallingShell.animate({"width":"250px"}, 500);
        });
      }
    }
```

And the replay needs the inline css create by the js reset. See: http://api.jquery.com/css/

I think this is everything you need to reset, but this is a best guess having not seen the code.

```
var resetSlides = function(){
    $(".falling").css(
      "width":"auto",
      "opacity":"0",
      "top":"0px"
    );
}
```

So then you can tie it all together with a `click` or timer or something, or even call the reset at the start of `animateSlides();`

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
  resetSlides();
  animateSlides();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Any thoughts on how it could transition with the width instead of just flashing like that at the end / complete? Also, where do you suggest having the replay falling reset css?

Comment: WIDTH: change it to `$fallingShell.animate({"width":"250px"}, 500);`